# generate XML data for a parent child tables

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to generate XML from parent child tables. Here is the XML format I am trying to achieve. The PHP code only works for one table. I am not sure how to generate XML from a child table. I appreciate any help.

```
  <SalesOrder>
    <Sales>
     <SalesOrderNumber>SO43660</SalesOrderNumber>
     <PurchaseOrderNumber>PO18850127500</PurchaseOrderNumber>
     <AccountNumber>3333</AccountNumber>
     <OrderDate>2001-07-01</OrderDate>
     <Details>
       <SalesOrderDetailID>13</SalesOrderDetailID>
       <Name>Road-650 Red, 44</Name>
       <CarrierTrackingNumber>6431-4D57-83</CarrierTrackingNumber>
     </Details>
     <Details>
      <SalesOrderDetailID>14</SalesOrderDetailID>
      <Name>Road-450 Red, 52</Name>
      <CarrierTrackingNumber>6431-4D57-83</CarrierTrackingNumber>
    </Details>
   </Sales>
  </SalesOrder>
```

Here is PHP code.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from table1");

header("Content-Type: application/xml");
echo sqlToXml($result, "SalesOrder", "sales");

function sqlToXml($queryResult, $rootElementName, $childElementName)
{

$xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" ?>\n"; 
$xmlData .= "<" . $rootElementName . ">";

while($record = mysql_fetch_object($queryResult))
{ 
    $xmlData .= "<" . $childElementName . ">";
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($queryResult); $i++)
    { 
        $fieldName = mysql_field_name($queryResult, $i); 
        $xmlData .= "<" . $fieldName . ">";
        if(!empty($record->$fieldName))
            $xmlData .= $record->$fieldName; 
        else
            $xmlData .= "null"; 

        $xmlData .= "</" . $fieldName . ">"; 
    } 
    $xmlData .= "</" . $childElementName . ">"; 
} 
$xmlData .= "</" . $rootElementName . ">"; 
}
```

Here is the schema.

```
SalesOrder Table                              SalesOrderDetail
----------------                              ------------------
SalesOrderNumber Varchar(20)                  SalesOrderDetailID    INT
PurchaseOrderNumber Varchar(20)               SalesOrderNumber      Varchar(20)
AccountNumber       Varchar(20)               Name                  Varchar(30)    
OrderDate           Date                      CarrierTrackingNumber  Varchar(30)
```

Comment: What do you mean by child table ? can you include the schema(s) and an example of the data in each ... Thanks

Comment: I updated with schema. The example data is in my xml file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between these 2 lines :

```
} 
$xmlData .= "</" . $childElementName . ">";
```

add the following :

```
$detail = mysql_query("SELECT * from table2 WHERE salesordernumber = '".$record->SalesOrderNumber."'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($detail)) { 
   $xmlData .= "<Details>";
   $xmlData .= "<SalesOrderDetailID>" . $row->SalesOrderDetailID . "</SalesOrderDetailID>";
   $xmlData .= "<Name>" . $row->Name . "</Name>";
   $xmlData .= "<CarrierTrackingNumber>" . $row->CarrierTrackingNumber . "</CarrierTrackingNumber>";
   $xmlData .= "</Details>";
}
```

The first line runs the query to get the data from the second table
The second line is a loop over the returned records - making `$row` an object of each record. Everything within the while loop adds to the XML string (`$xmlData`)

Link to [mysql_fetch_object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) Docs